# How to get/post the values in PHP from a dynamically form which add automatically input form elements

Tags: php, jquery

So my form is creating Dynamically forms based on the Total Person.
It the Total Person is: **3**

Then 3 Forms will appear with each different "valuenames" like:

```
<input name="lastname[1]">
<input name="lastname[2]">
<input name="lastname[3]">
```

But how can I call the results of each input in $POST PHP?

See this picture what I mean:

[image]

I need to show, get, call that values in php.

So it is the print, I need to post each values of this arrays to send the results as a mail:

```
**[lastname] => Array ( [1] => MARVIN [2] => JIM [3] => ZOO**
```

Example:

```
Lastname 1: MARVIN
Lastname 2: JIM
Lastname 3: ZOO
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will postfix a variable with a number to evaluate, and the for loop will loop over 0 to 4 (which is 5 fields in total) and then echo out the result.

You will have to adapt the code to match your other form variables.

```
<?php

for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){

    $var = 'lastname'.$i;

    if(isset($_POST[$var])){
        echo $_POST[$var];
    }
}

?>

<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="<? $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="lastname1" />
    <input type="text" name="lastname2" />
    <input type="text" name="lastname3" />
    <input type="text" name="lastname4" />
    <input type="text" name="lastname5" />
    <input type="submit" value="test">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is not working because if the total person is 20, should i add 20 of that inputs?? And also is the value lastname[1]

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment - I read your question again and I can see the JSfiddle that you sent. i) Change the jquery to remove the [ ] - then in PHP try use $_POST['vol'] as the total number to loop over. This is the Person drop down. That will make the above for loop dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you do get the values on your array. but your php code is beginners, cut, paste, adaptation and "happy thinking", We all started one day, so I will review it in some detail.

You initiate your loop with

$message .=

should be:

$message =

As you are initiating a mesagge, not concatenating to it...

Then you follow it up with:

$message =

when now, you are concatenating to $message, it should be

$message .=

read: [languaje operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Then kind of really basic stuff,

Then you follow messsage = with "White space", so the php processor goes reading until a statement closure ";" is found. The parser wont find it because it keeps reading into yor message string until "From" is found. 
That is because the parser either finds a literal string between "" or '' or a concatenation operator ".", for which the parser will add the variable value between concatenators.
As you can check, those two conditions are met until the "From" is encountered at which point the parse will throw an error because it is either expecting an statment closure ";" or a new concatenation operator, but finds a literal.

If you did not catch it probably you need to turn on error reporting:

Put this at the begining of the page: (Do take those out in production!!)

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set("display_errors", 0);
```

Happy coding!

Nevertheless, althoug some times work, it is absolutely recommended no to span comands over several lines.

There are two choices, concaternate for every line, like you have in the $headers secction...

Or use the heredoc syntax although that takes some practice to master.

Heredoc sintax will take anythin between the "<<

Additionally the parser will greedily look for variables or unidimensional array variables and replace them with their values, more complex values should be enclosed by curly braces, just for helping you start,  here is the revised php code with the $meesage block under heredoc syntax an, but do read this basic page if you want to make some progress:

[php strings manual](https://php.net/language.types.string)

here is the revised php code:

```
      <?php

  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set("display_errors", 0);

  foreach($_POST['name'] as $index => $name)
       { // Just for clarity sake,Obtain this person information. similarly could have been done inside the $message build, 
         // Left bornday to show how is that done......
       $Passenger  =  ($index);
       $Name  = $name;
       $LastName = $_POST['lastname'][$index];     
       $BornDay = $_POST['bornday'][$index];     
       $Trip = $_POST['destination'][$index];     
       $Persons = $_POST['vol'][$index];     
       $Kids = $_POST['kinderen'][$index];     
       $Babys = $_POST['Babys'][$index];     


  $message .= <<<EOD         
  Trip: $Trip<br><br>
  Persons: $Persons<br>
  Kids:  $Kids<br>
  Babys: $Babys<br><br>
  Personsinformation:   $Name  $LastName   {$_POST['bornday'][$index]  <br><br>
  EOD;

  // DBG // Show the message
  echo "The $index message  is: $message<br>";

  // Sending mail dpends a bit on you enviroment, supposig this applies:

  $headers = 'From:' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Reply-To:' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; ";
  $headers .= "boundary=$num\r\n";
  $headers .= "--$num\r\n";  

  // Define the message section
  $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:8bit\r\n\n";
  $headers .= "$message\r\n";
  $headers .= "--$num\r\n";

  // Send email

  mail ($to, $subject, '', $headers);
  print_r($_POST);
  }

  ?>
```

Comment: Thanks i know that but the code was not finished yet, its only for testing .. But this is NOT the answer on the QUESTION

Comment: It was part of your original question, which was by no means clear. By the time I wrote my answer your question has been edited and now it does not include the php code. Nevertherless if you do have the pos array you posted, this php would fill the e-mail part of your original post.

Comment: In general terms, your $_POST array will contain an array of values on each of you indexed fields like $_POST['name'][index], so, name[0] would be $_POST['name'][0], name[1] would be $_POST['name'][1], 
Interstingly you can traverse the array with a "foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)" on any of the indexed fields on your form  an use the index to obtain the other values, in the case of you php code the index was pulled out from the "gender" field. change it to "name" if you want, but the results would be the same.

Comment: I think I over respoded yor question because my answer gets you all the way to sending your mails which the last part of your question,

Comment: Jaja... Just checked my code answer and still  has some messy stuff, i will repost the code in a few minutes  to fully comply to your question.